# python not using latest numpy version

Tags: python, linux, path

I have a problem.
I need numpy 1.14.2, and my machine (Linux Mint 17.3) has only 1.8.2 installed.
I then installed 1.14.2 through pip. But when I load it in ipython, it still says that it is 1.8.2.
Using yolk I saw that 1.14.2 is actually installed, but marked as non-active.

> numpy           - 1.14.2       - non-active development
>   (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages)

While for 1.8.2 it says "active".

Also, 1.8.2 is located in "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy".

Why is there a difference? I dont see a reason why there are two libraries.
I read that python loads the libraries by the order in $PATH.
And indeed, when I look at sys.path, I see that /usr/lib... is listet before /usr/local ....
How can I change that? I dont have anything in .bashrc, /etc/profile or /etc/rc.local which would set this specific order.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a virtual environment. Your system most likely will default to the most up to date version. 
Try installing:

`pip install virtualenv`

then run:
`virtualenv -p python2.7 environment_name`.

Source the virtualenv with:
`source environment_name/bin/activate`

then `pip install numpy=1.14.2`.

Then you will have a mini environment with the exact version you want and wont update. This way you can have multiple versions all contained in the same system.

Comment: I am not sure this is viable for me. I need the up to date numpy version for a different software that needs this. I don't think I can, or want to, install all of the new software in a new virtual environment.

Comment: you definitely can! the whole point of environments is to run different versions and such self contained.

Comment: @Pythoneer Id recommend uninstalling numpy then installing the required version you need for your system wide application and using virtual environments for any other usage

Comment: I tried a apt-get purge, but that wants to get rid of cinnamon, and thats not an option. Or would a apt-get remove just uninstall numpy without touching packages that depend on it?

Comment: I do not see why you cannot just uninstall and reinstall all dependencies but you can do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall {package}={version number}`